# yii2 custom REST api issue

Tags: api, yii2

I have tried all the way to make these run but no use.There is lots of problem and confusion i m going through.
I have make api which return all the countries which is working fine.Now need to write api function to list all the states of perticular country.

api : http://phpserver:8090/ssn-project/newzit/api/web/state/customstate?country_id=102

StateController.php

```
class StateController extends ActiveController{

public $modelClass = 'api\modules\state\models\State'; 

public function actionCustomState($country_id)
{
    $model = new $this->modelClass;
    $result = $model::find()
              ->where(['country_id' => $country_id])
              ->all();
    return $result;
}  
}
```

main.php

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
                'controller' => ['country/country','state/state','category/category','seller/seller'],
                'extraPatterns' => [
                    'GET CustomState' => 'CustomState',
                ],  
            ]
        ],        
    ]
```

Am I doing anything wrong.Please help

Comment: Are you getting a specific error?

Comment: yes {
  "name": "Not Found",
  "message": "Page not found.",
  "code": 0,
  "status": 404,
  "type": "yii\\web\\NotFoundHttpException"
} I am constantly facing same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.
made 'pluralize'=>false and used custom-state in url
My main.php

```
'rules' => [
            [
                'pluralize'=>false,
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
                'controller' => ['country/country','state/state','category/category','seller/seller','contactus/contactus'],
                'extraPatterns' => [
                    'GET custom-state' => 'custom-state',
                ],  

            ]
        ],
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by `'controller' => ['country/country','state/state','category/category','seller/seller']` ? This will be treated as module/controller. You have placed all controllers inside different modules? With this logic, your api url will be

http://phpserver:8090/ssn-project/newzit/api/web/state/state/customstate?country_id=102

instead of

http://phpserver:8090/ssn-project/newzit/api/web/state/customstate?country_id=102

Comment: Have you tried either `customState` or `custom-state` as the action in the urls?

Comment: Can you show part of Yii app log? It can be helpful to solve your issue. Logs in standard Yii installation can be found in runtime/logs.